# How do I set a variable with the value being a random range, with variables set to have a random range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, module

I have this variable called "number" with the range being the variables "a" and "b". These range variables are ranges themselves.

```
from random import *

a = randint(1, 99)
b = randint(2, 100)

number = randint(a, b)
print(number)
```

When I try to enter this code, I occasionally receive an integer or get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    number = randint(a, b)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 248, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 226, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d, %d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (17, 6, -11)
```

Comment: `range` with start > stop values is an empty object.

Comment: Do this: *b = randint(a, 100)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that the first parameter passed to *randint* is less than or equal to the second parameter. How about:

```
from random import randint

a = randint(1, 99)
b = randint(a, 100)
number = randint(a, b)
print(number)
```

...which is equivalent to:

```
from random import randint

number = randint(1, 100)
print(number)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, I now understand now why my code was not working.

Answer (score 1):

**randint(a, b)** has a condition.

```
a <= b
```

Since you are generating a and b as random range, sometimes a is greater than b. You need to adjust your a and b range so that a is always less than or equal to b.

```
a = randint(1, 50)
b = randint(50, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

As your range for `randint` needs to consist of a lower and upper boundary, your script will occasionally break when `b` is randomly lower than `a`. To prevent this, make sure `b` cannot be lower than `a`. An example:

```
from random import *

a = randint(1, 99)
b = randint(a, 100)

number = randint(a, b)
print(number)
```

Comment: You really should not use a while loop like that. *b = randint(a, 100)* is more appropriate

Comment: @Cobra agreed, edited

Answer (score -2):

Using this it seems to do the job you asked.

```
import random

a = random.randint(1, 99)
b = random.randint(2, 100)

number = random.randint(a, b)
print(number)
```

I don't have any error running this.

Comment: With this code *a* could be greater than *b* which will induce ValueError

Comment: Your solution does absolutely nothing to resolve the issue. All you did is import in a different way

Comment: Didn't think about the a being greater than b... Thx for correcting me Cobra